# What is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\tan^{-1}\left(x^{2}\right)+1}-\frac{2}{\pi+2}\right)dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I was messing around in Desmos and noticed that $\frac{1}{\tan^{-1}\left(x^{2}\right)+1}$  had an asymptote at $y=\frac{2}{\pi+2}$. I wondered what $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\tan^{-1}\left(x^{2}\right)+1}-\frac{2}{\pi+2}\right)dx$ would be (assuming it converges) and Desmos gave me $1.14450701513$. However, I want an exact answer (in a closed form preferably) so I also tried to solve it analytically:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\tan^{-1}\left(x^{2}\right)+1}-\frac{2}{\pi+2}\right)dx$$

$$2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{u+1}-\frac{2}{\pi+2}\right)\frac{x^4+1}{2x}du$$

$$\frac{1}{\pi+2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\left(\pi-2u\right)\sec^{2}u}{\left(u+1\right)\sqrt{\tan u}}du$$

After integration by parts with help from @KStarGamer, I got:

$$2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sqrt{\tan u}}{\left(u+1\right)^{2}}du$$

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=series%20expansion%20of%20Divide%5BSqrt%5Btanx%5D%2CPower%5B%5C%2840%29x%2B1%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5D) says I can represent the integrand as:

$$x^\frac{1}{2}-2x^\frac{3}{2}+O(x^\frac{5}{2})$$

But I have not yet learned series expansions or big O notation so I may have made a mistake and I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Fwiw, you applied your substitution incorrectly, but doing it correctly and applying a round of integration by parts, $$I=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{(1+x)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ I would be surprised if this has a closed-form expression.

Comment: Another interesting expression is $I=\sqrt{2\pi}(1+i)\int_0^\infty e^{-(\frac\pi2+1)t}\left(\frac{\big(e^\frac{\pi t}2-1\big)\Gamma(\frac{i t}4+1)}{\Gamma(\frac{it}4+\frac12)}-\frac{\big(e^\frac{\pi t}2+1\big)\Gamma(\frac{it}4+\frac12)}{\Gamma(\frac{it}4)}\right)dt$ after Laplace transform

Comment: @KStarGamer I fixed my substitution and simplified further but I still don't see how integration by parts will lead me to your simplified integral

Comment: @DylanLevine Integrate $\frac{\sec^2 x}{\sqrt{\tan x}}$ and differentiate the rest.